# How may allowing HTML inside Twitter Bootstrap's tooltips cause XSS issues?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, xss

I was going through Twitter Bootstrap's docs on tooltips. It is stated there not to set `data-html=true` inside tooltips if you're worried about XSS attacks.

What `data-html=true` does is it allows you to write HTML in an element's `title` attribute.

I don't know anything about XSS attacks. I tried reading about it on Wikipedia but that wasn't much help.

Can you please explain:

1. How might it raise security issues?
2. What would be the secure way to allow HTML inside tooltips?

Comment: I'd start by reading https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet to understand the impact/attack vectors of XSS. The short answer is to only allow sanitized HTML anywhere there is a chance it can be executed. When in doubt, err on the side of not allowing HTML at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XSS means cross site scripting, so an XSS attack often involves injection of code (e.g. JS) into a site that then communicates with or initializes malicious code from another site/server.

1) It would raise security issues because unless `data-html` is set to `true` any HTML in the tooltip will be escaped / shown as text and not parsed.  If it is set to `true` the content will be parsed as HTML.  This means if you have user input variables displayed here that are not properly sanitized they could potentially inject malicious HTML code, for instance javascript that initiates an XSS attack.

2) Just make sure everything you are outputting in the tooltip is safe.  For example, if you let users enter information about themselves that is displayed in a tooltip make sure it is properly sanitized before you output it in the tooltip.

Comment: So that means it is safe to set `data-html` to `true` when some user-submitted information is not being displayed in there, right?

Comment: Well, it depends on what is in there and how you generate/populate it, but yes if you are completely confident it will be showing non-malicious code and there is no possibility of that happening it should be okay.  "Safe" is a very relative term on the internet when it comes to this sort of thing though.

Comment: Naively, I was about to override the (conservative) default behavior with something like `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({'html': true});`, and then realized that I could allow HTML on a per-element basis with `data-html="true"`, which is much safer. Yes, this is "Twitter Bootstrap JS API 101", but worth noting all the same.